# Firebase Security Rules: Guard against reserved chars

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Firebase has certain reserved characters:

```
., $, #, [, ], /
```

How do I block these characters from being added into my database in security rules?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.validate` along with `matches()`. `matches()` accepts regular expressions. `contains()` checks if the string contains the specified value.

This would be if you were writing an object like this: `{"post": "he.lo"}`

```
".validate": "!(newData.child('post').val().matches(/[.$\/#]/) || newData.child('post').val().contains(']') || newData.child('post').val().contains('['))"
```

And if you were just writing a string: "he.lo"

```
".validate": "!(newData.val().matches(/[.$\/#]/) || newData.val().contains(']') || newData.val().contains('['))"
```

I tried for quite some time to include "[" and "]", but Firebase didn't like them which is why I added the `contains()` methods.

These rules would be used for checking against values and, as @Frank said, not keys.

Reference: [Firebase 3.0 Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex#supported_features)

Answer (score 0):

These characters cannot be used in database *keys*, but can be used in database values.

The Firebase Database will automatically rejects write operations where such characters appear in a key, you don't have to write any rules for that.